# How to find close GPS co-ordinates in large table at a given time

Tags: algorithm, gps

*(This is a theoretical question for a system design I am working on - advising changes is great)*
I have a large table of GPS data which contains the following rows:

- locID - PK
- userID - User ID of the user of the app
- lat
- long
- timestamp - point in UNIX time when this data was recorded

I am trying to design a way which will allow a server to go through this dataset and check if any "users" were in a specific "place" together (eg. 50m apart) at a specific time range (2min) - eg. did user1 visit the same vicinity of user2 within that 2min time gap.

The only way I can currently think of is check each row one by one with all the rows in the same timeframe using a co-ordinate distance check algorithm. - But this comes up with the issue if the users are all around the world and have thousands maybe millions of rows in that 5min timeframe this would not work efficiently.

Also what if I want to know how long they were in each others vicinity?

Any ideas/thoughts would be helpful. Including the database to use? I am thinking either PostgreSQL or maybe Cassandra. And the table layout. All help appreciated.

Comment: How realistic is it that you will have millions of users in a 5-minute time period?  There is a big difference between "thousands" and "millions".  For thousands, you can easily do this math in your query.  Also, it is pretty easy to optimize your query to get general vicinity before calculating whether or not they are in the same radius circle.  And, will you have to query all these simultaneously?  Do you need to know every second all of the geographical collisions?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: This is for a system which may scale to millions of users, and with the ability at the start to handle that many it will be perfect.
Every through a 5min period for example we may get 1 million users locations. We would want to check as often as possible with a minimum of every 30seconds. Potentially "drawing lines" of where this person may have been and they crossed paths at some point in that 5minutes. We need to know if they had in general crossed paths in a radius, and how long were they in that radius is the next level up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Divide the globe into patches, where each patch is small enough to contain only a few thousand people, say 200m by 200m, and add the `patchID` as an attribute to each entry in the database. Note that two users cannot be in close proximity if they aren't in the same patch or in adjacent patches. Therefore, when checking for two users in the same place at a given time, query the database for a given `patchID` and the eight surrounding `patchIDs`, to get a subset of the database that may contain possible collisions.

Comment: That's a good idea, but what's the best way to do those calculations?

Comment: The math for computing the distance between two lat/long points is discussed in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance).